# System.FormatException: Invalid format. While trying to add a Header Key

Tags: c#, api

I have a function where I call an API, to add a key authorization to the response header.

That is : `_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", accessToken);`

However I have a function, where I will repetedly call the same function until I get all results based on a predefined Page Size.

Here how ever when the first time the function is called the above function is working perfectly, however subsequent recursive calls to the same function,  throw an error **System.FormatException: Invalid format.**

Stack Trace :

```
System.FormatException: Invalid format.
  at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddInternal (System.String name, IEnumerable`1 values, System.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderInfo headerInfo, Boolean ignoreInvalid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add (System.String name, IEnumerable`1 values) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add (System.String name, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at  (System.String verb, System.String url, System.String parameters) [0x00041] in
```

Comment: What is the value for `accessToken`?

Comment: Also, `DefaultRequestHeaders` headers should be added before you perform any request

Comment: Thanks it is solved, that defaultheaderrequest was already having same Key added to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaultheaderrequest was already having same Key added to it in a previous request.

Hence I would require those keys to clear it then add again using,

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
```